# firebird MON$STATEMENTS insert, delete, update

Tags: sql, firebird, performance

I use 2.1 firebird.

I see the select commands but I not found `insert`, `update`, `delete` commands when `MON$STATE = 0`.
Why can't see `insert`, `update`, `delete` command in `MON$STATEMENTS` table after these run?
I see these when their `MON$STATE = 1` but I not find these when their `MON$STATE = 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MON$STATE = 1** means that a query being executed right now. **MON$STATE = 0** means that a **SELECT** query has been executed and is in a suspended state. i.e. either waits for a row being fetched by a client application or an end of a record set is reached but query is not closed yet.

INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries don't have a **SUSPENDED** state. They are either running or finished and gone.

Comment: I suspect - but didn't test - that `INSERT ... RETURNING <columns>` (and similar for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` will also have a suspended state.

Comment: Don't think so. Queries with RETURNING clause work like not selectable procedures which return parameters.

Comment: Not as far as I know, a `RETURNING` clause on an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` can return multiple rows, and as far as I know it is handled the same as a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: When a statement hasn't been freed/closed yet, it will have MON$STATE = 0, eg for a prepared statement, see my answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel according to FB manual, `RETURNING` supports singletons only. It won't open a cursor to process multiple records

Comment: @Fr0sT you are entirely right, an unfortunate limitation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel probably it is but I see the developers' point clearly. Just copying some values is much more light operation than creating a cursor with all the underwater stuff. For such rare cases there are powerful `execute block` constructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `MON$STATE = 0` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. When your application uses prepared statements and the statement is not executing, the `MON$STATEMENTS` row for that query will also have `MON$STATE = 0`.